# How to minimize this loss function?

Tags: loss-functions, log-loss

I have a loss function 
$L = \sum_i I(\text{log_loss}_i > 0.6)$, where $I$ is the indicator function (equals 0 when argument is false, 1 otherwise) and log_loss$_i$ is the log loss of the $i^{th}$ group of sample points.

My instinct is to minimize this using the hinge loss, but is there a better way?

More info:

So I've got data from a bunch of different domains which are all very similar and I want a classifier that does "quite well" in all domains (including potentially future unseen ones). The issue with training a network or a boosting model on the cross entropy is that sometimes it focuses too hard on a single domain, making performance slightly worse in another domain.

The loss function above encapsulates what I want to achieve. I want to minimize the count of the number of eras which have a log-loss bigger than 0.6. Since the above has a 0-1 loss ($I$), I figured one way would be to replace this with a hinge loss (or even exponential loss). Both approaches sort of work - but I'm sure there's something better.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? "How to minimize" sounds like you want to use an optimization algorithm to find parameters that minimize $L$ (if that's the case, please specify the full function). But then you say "minimize using the hinge loss". What would it mean to minimize a loss function using another loss function?

Comment: @user20160 I've just updated the question with info on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It's clearer now, but I'm still a bit confused by how you're using the word "loss". A loss function expresses the goodness/badness of a candidate solution, but it sounds like you might also be using it to refer to components of this function (e.g. loss function $L$ "has a 0-1 loss" to mean it uses the indicator function). Using the hinge loss would typically be taken to mean that $L$ itself *is* the hinge loss function. But, are you actually asking about something like $L = \sum_i \max(0, \text{log_loss}_i - .6)$?

Comment: @user20160 yes the last equation you wrote (based on the hinge loss) is exactly what I'm thinking about!

Comment: Is this a valid thing to do? Are these loss functions doing what I think they should be doing?